# C++-Assembly linking on x86 / ubuntu - undefined reference to ThreadRoot, SWITCH

Tags: linux, gcc, x86, g++, x86-64

I am building Nachos source on Ubuntu 12.04

If we believe "lscpu" output, machine arch is x86. I am getting the following error at the last step of make:

$ make

g++ -m32 -P -I../network -I../filesys -I../userprog -I../threads -I../machine -I../lib -iquote -Dx86 -DLINUX -c ../threads/switch.S

g++ bitmap.o debug.o libtest.o sysdep.o interrupt.o stats.o timer.o console.o machine.o mipssim.o translate.o network.o disk.o alarm.o kernel.o main.o scheduler.o synch.o thread.o addrspace.o exception.o synchconsole.o directory.o filehdr.o filesys.o pbitmap.o openfile.o synchdisk.o post.o switch.o -m32 -o nachos

scheduler.o: In function `Scheduler::Run(Thread*, bool)':

/home/userx/nachos/NachOS-4.0/code/build.linux/../threads/scheduler.cc:133: undefined reference to `SWITCH'

thread.o: In function `Thread::StackAllocate(void (*)(void*), void*)':

/home/userx/nachos/NachOS-4.0/code/build.linux/../threads/thread.cc:345: undefined reference to `ThreadRoot'

/home/userx/nachos/NachOS-4.0/code/build.linux/../threads/thread.cc:356: undefined reference to `ThreadRoot'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [nachos] Error 1
$

Here is the switch.S that has the symbol defs --

```
/* We define two routines for each architecture:
 *
 * ThreadRoot(InitialPC, InitialArg, WhenDonePC, StartupPC)

<...>

#ifdef SOLARIS
  .globl  ThreadRoot
  ThreadRoot:
#else
  .globl  _ThreadRoot
  _ThreadRoot:
#endif

#ifdef x86
    .text
    .align  2
  .globl  ThreadRoot
  .globl  _ThreadRoot
  _ThreadRoot:
  ThreadRoot:
  <...>
    .globl  SWITCH
  .globl  _SWITCH
  _SWITCH:
  SWITCH:
  <...>
#endif
```

I have skipped the #ifdefs for more arch like DECMIPS, POWERPC, APPLEPOWERPC etc.
Yes, my env $PATH includes dir where switch.s resides :/home/userx/nachos/NachOS-4.0/code/threads/ 
Please let me know if any more info is needed to debug. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding underscore in the C header file that have extern "C" SWITCH and ThreadRoot, and change too the .c file in where the error is. I mean use _SWITCH instead SWITCH and the same for ThreadRoot.